# How to check the function name if already exists in wordpress?

Tags: function, wordpress

I created the two small wordpress plugin in a seperate field. That menu title is displaying under the settings of admin page Because of I created this like

```
add_submenu_page('options-general.php','Fantastic Copyright by FantasticPlugins.com', 'Fantastic Copyright', 'manage_options', 'copyright_admin', 'copyright_admin_page');
```

Here is the screenshot of the admin side.

[image]

Now I want to display My Individual Plugins in a common Menu. Even I tried to create the menu and the submenu for the plugin  that i googling and added.

```
 add_menu_page('My Test Plugin Settings', 'Test Plugin',IC_MYPLUGIN_PERMISSIONS,"my-plugin-slug", "ic_myplugin_settings",plugins_url('fp.ico', __FILE__));
     // create a new submenu
    add_submenu_page(
        "my-plugin-slug",
        __("This is page title for the page"),
        __("Settings"),
        IC_MYPLUGIN_PERMISSIONS,
        "my-plugin-slug",
        "ic_myplugin_settings"
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        "my-plugin-slug",
        __("This is page title for items page"),
        __("Items"),
        IC_MYPLUGIN_PERMISSIONS,
        "my-plugin-slug-items",
        "ic_myplugin_items"
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        "my-plugin-slug",
        __("This is page title for add item page"),
        __("Add Item"),
        IC_MYPLUGIN_PERMISSIONS,
        "my-plugin-slug-add-item",

        "ic_myplugin_add_item"
    );
}
```

[image]

From the Picture Test Plugin Is the common menu In that we created the manual submenu. Now I need to Know How to add the single plugin into submenu page of test plugin. I need to make the menu independent. For example if i create the plugin for the wordpress. In that we create Image Gallery As seperate Plugin and Video Gallery as seperate Plugin.

```
Wordpress --> Is the Main Menu 
         Image Gallery --> Is the sub Menu and Seperate Plugin
         Video Gallery --> Is the sub menu and seperate Plugin
```

Like that I need to display. Whatever I create the plugin for the wordpress is goes under the common main menu of wordpress. Any One tell me how can i do this stuff ??

Comment: r u trying to take ur Fantastic Copyright to your test plugin?

Comment: yes @anstrangel0ver How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do is you need to add your plugin add_submenu_page function first paramater as your parent slug in your case it is..

```
add_submenu_page('my-plugin-slug','Fantastic Copyright by FantasticPlugins.com', 'Fantastic Copyright', 'manage_options', 'copyright_admin', 'copyright_admin_page');
```

do this with all your plugins

hope this is what you are looking for :)

update part:-

you have main menu

```
    add_menu_page('My Test Plugin Settings', 'Test Plugin',IC_MYPLUGIN_PERMISSIONS,"my-plugin-slug", "ic_myplugin_settings",plugins_url('fp.ico', __FILE__));
    if(function_exists(ic_myplugin_settings)){
$menu-slug='my-plugin-slug'
     add_submenu_page($menu-slug,'Fantastic Copyright by FantasticPlugins.com', 'Fantastic Copyright', 'manage_options', 'copyright_admin', 'copyright_admin_page');
    }
    else {
$menu-slug=$menu_slug
    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
    }
```

goes on.. hope you got some idea for thes you can carry on . m in rush now ;)

Comment: Yes Here is the one that i looking for If the parent slug is not active means what we do ? Is the parent slug work or else ?

Comment: if parent slug is not active den it wont work. the parent menu page must be there or what you will like to do any idea you have?

Comment: Is it possible way to check the parent slug is active . If active using the parent slug to create the sub menu or else to create the main menu and also the sub menu is it possible ? ? ?

Comment: individually it is possible you can use condition for that but i think you can check it for some define ones like in heirracy types ok i will give u certain idea check my edited part might that be working using if( function_exists()){ }

Comment: Awesome Explanation for this . . . .I really Fixed the Problem . without Your Help I can't Be done thanks. . . .